# python xpath selector from div

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I started playing with python and come across something that should be very simple but I cannot make it work...
I had below HTML

```
<h2 class="sr-only">Available Products</h2>
<div id="productlistcontainer" data-defaultpageno="1" data-descfilter="" class="columns4 columnsmobile2" data-noproductstext="No Products Found" data-defaultsortorder="rank" data-fltrselectedcurrency="GBP" data-category="Category1" data-productidstodisableshortcutbuttons="976516" data-defaultpagelength="100" data-searchtermcategory="" data-noofitemsingtmpost="25">
    <ul id="navlist" class="s-productscontainer2">
```

What I need is to use parser.xpath to get value of data-category element.

Im trying for example:

```
cgy = xpath('//div["data-category"]')
```

What Im doing wrong ?

Comment: what is parser? And what are you expecting to return?

Comment: Ignore "parser."  , I need to understand how to get string "Category1" which is assigned to data-category from above html

Comment: @kunduK has given the answer I would (+) then as you need to extract the attribute value. Use select and index if not the first or select_one if the first.

Comment: Just fyi, your `<div>` and `<ul>` tags aren't closed; don't know if that's relevant to anything, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I use `lxml html` to do my parsing because it is fast and easy to work with in my opinion. I could of shorten up how the `category` is actually being extracted but I wanted to show you as much detail as possible so you can understand what is going on.

```
from lxml import html

def extract_data_category(tree):
    elements = [
        e
        for e in tree.cssselect('div#productlistcontainer')
        if e.get('data-category') is not None
    ]
    element = elements[0]
    content = element.get('data-category')
    return content

response = """
<h2 class="sr-only">Available Products</h2>
<div id="productlistcontainer" data-defaultpageno="1" data-descfilter="" class="columns4 columnsmobile2" data-noproductstext="No Products Found" data-defaultsortorder="rank" data-fltrselectedcurrency="GBP" data-category="Category1" data-productidstodisableshortcutbuttons="976516" data-defaultpagelength="100" data-searchtermcategory="" data-noofitemsingtmpost="25">
<ul id="navlist" class="s-productscontainer2">
"""

tree = html.fromstring(response)
data_category = extract_data_category(tree)
print (data_category)
```

Comment: thank you , do you know what would be equivalent of above functionality by using
import requests
requests.get (xxx)

Comment: What is the website you are trying to `request`? But I do think that has to be another question as you did not ask anything about `requests` in this question.

Comment: Your solution is working fine if data-category exist in HTML , if it hits page where data-category do not exist   im getting error "Index out of range" - which means empty list.
I was trying to add IF after elements but this doesent change anything:
element = elements.append('abc') if len(elements) == 0 else elements[0]

Comment: Well of course, can easily add in error handling. You could even save the response to a file and look it over to see why data-category is not there. This was just a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

Try Selenium `webdriver` with python.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("url here")
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='productlistcontainer']")
print(element.get_attribute('data-category'))
```

---

Or you can use Beautifulsoup which is python library.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

doc = """
<h2 class="sr-only">Available Products</h2>
<div id="productlistcontainer" data-defaultpageno="1" data-descfilter="" class="columns4 columnsmobile2" data-noproductstext="No Products Found" data-defaultsortorder="rank" data-fltrselectedcurrency="GBP" data-category="Category1" data-productidstodisableshortcutbuttons="976516" data-defaultpagelength="100" data-searchtermcategory="" data-noofitemsingtmpost="25">
    <ul id="navlist" class="s-productscontainer2">
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(doc,'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('div#productlistcontainer')['data-category'])
```